# Android NDK Compile Protobuf error

Tags: android-ndk, protocol-buffers

I try to compile ProtoBuf 2.5 with NDK.But when I build ProtoBuf 2.5 in eclipse, I get error info as below in console

```
bash "E:\\Android\\android-ndk-r8e\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
E:\Android\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd: line 1: @echo: command not found
E:\Android\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd: line 2: rem: command not found
E:\Android\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd: line 6: rem: command not found
E:\Android\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd: line 7: goto: command not found
E:\Android\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd: line 8: :FOO: command not found
E:\Android\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd: line 27: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I didn't edited ndk-build.cmd.
Please help me! Thandks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Eclipse is calling `ndk-build.cmd`, but your shell is a Cygwin/MinGW shell. You need to call the `ndk-build` script, not `ndk-build.cmd`